# the node reducer and edge reducer here are not working for my map

Tags: angular, renderer, sigma.js, graphology

[image: node reducer code]
in angular when hovered over certain node the nodes that are not connected to selected node have to be grayed out but its not working for me and i don't see any error either. [image: the map]

the code in sandbox works perfectly fine and i tried to implement this in angular in typescript and the reducer function is not working
i tried rendering the function in init but every node grayed out
here is my code:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import Sigma from 'sigma';
import Graph from 'graphology';
import { Coordinates, EdgeDisplayData, NodeDisplayData } from 'sigma/types';
import data from './data.json';

interface State {
  hoveredNode?: string;
  searchQuery: string;
  selectedNode?: string;
  suggestions?: Set<string>;
  hoveredNeighbors?: Set<string>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `
    <div id="sigma-container" style="height: 400px;"></div>
    <input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
    <datalist id="suggestions"></datalist>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {
  private graph: Graph;
  private renderer: Sigma | null = null;
  private state: State = {
    searchQuery: "",
    suggestions: new Set<string>()
  };

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.graph = new Graph();
  }
  

  ngOnInit() {
    this.graph.import(data);
    this.renderer = new Sigma(this.graph, this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#sigma-container'));

    this.renderer.on('enterNode', ({ node }) => {
      this.setHoveredNode(node);
    });
    this.renderer.on('leaveNode', () => {
      this.setHoveredNode(undefined);
    });

    

    const searchInput = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#search-input') as HTMLInputElement;
    const searchSuggestions = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#suggestions') as HTMLDataListElement;

    searchSuggestions.innerHTML = this.graph
      .nodes()
      .map((node) => `<option value="${this.graph.getNodeAttribute(node, 'label')}"></option>`)
      .join('\n');

    searchInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
      this.setSearchQuery(searchInput.value || '');
    });

    searchInput.addEventListener('blur', () => {
      this.setSearchQuery('');
    });
  }
   





  
  setSearchQuery(query: string) {
    this.state.searchQuery = query;

    const searchInput = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#search-input') as HTMLInputElement;

    if (searchInput.value !== query) searchInput.value = query;

    if (query) {
      const lcQuery = query.toLowerCase();
      const suggestions = this.graph
        .nodes()
        .map((n) => ({ id: n, label: this.graph.getNodeAttribute(n, 'label') as string }))
        .filter(({ label }) => label.toLowerCase().includes(lcQuery))
        .map(({ id }) => id);

      if (suggestions.length === 1 && suggestions[0] === query) {
        this.state.selectedNode = suggestions[0];
        this.state.suggestions!.clear();

        const nodePosition = this.renderer!.getNodeDisplayData(this.state.selectedNode) as Coordinates;
        this.renderer!.getCamera().animate(nodePosition, {
          duration: 500
        });
      } else {
        this.state.selectedNode = undefined;
        this.state.suggestions = new Set<string>(suggestions);
      }
    } else {
      this.state.selectedNode = undefined;
      this.state.suggestions!.clear();
    }

    this.renderer!.refresh();
  }

  setHoveredNode(node?: string) {
    if (node) {
      this.state.hoveredNode = node;
      this.state.hoveredNeighbors = new Set<string>(this.graph.neighbors(node));
    } else {
      this.state.hoveredNode = undefined;
      this.state.hoveredNeighbors = undefined;
    }

    this.renderer!.refresh();
  }

  nodeReducer = (node: string, data: NodeDisplayData): Partial<NodeDisplayData> => {
    const res: Partial<NodeDisplayData> = { ...data };

    if (this.state.hoveredNeighbors && !this.state.hoveredNeighbors.has(node) && this.state.hoveredNode != node) {
      res.label = '';
      res.color = '#f6f6f6';
    }

    if (this.state.selectedNode === node || (this.state.suggestions && this.state.suggestions.has(node))) {
      res.highlighted = true;
    }

    return res;
  };

  edgeReducer = (edge: string, data: EdgeDisplayData): Partial<EdgeDisplayData> => {
    const res: Partial<EdgeDisplayData> = { ...data };

    if (
      this.state.hoveredNode &&
      (!this.graph.hasExtremity(edge, this.state.hoveredNode) ||
      (this.state.suggestions &&
      (!this.state.suggestions.has(this.graph.source(edge)) || !this.state.suggestions.has(this.graph.target(edge)))))
    ) {
      res.hidden = true;
    }

    return res;
  };
}
```